# can I fill only raw value 100 for "Name" instead of ValueKind = Number : "100

Tags: c#, .net-core

One of C# 3rd party library serialize/deserialize things like `System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer`, not using  `Newtonsoft` like below example,

```
string test = "[{\"Id\":86,\"Name\":\"test\"},{\"Id\":87,\"Name\":100}]";
        var SystemTextJson = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<Data>>(test);

 public class Data
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public object Name { get; set; }
}
```

Here `Name` is `object` type and this works, but I am seeing `valueKind = Number : "100"` and `valueKind = string : "test"`. Can I fill the `Name` only with raw value `100`, `test`? how, please suggest.

[image]

Comment: will it be possible `Name=test` rather than  `valueKind = String : "test"`

Comment: `System.Text.Json` is built-in api, the value shown in debugger is internal implementation

Comment: So you want to deserialize as `string`, `int`, `double`, etc. automagically instead of as `JsonElement`?

Comment: Yes John, you are corrct

Comment: You should tag your question appropriately. [It seems](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonserializer) it's .Net Core 3 application, which e.g. I am not able to test for you. But this problem is not exists with newtonsoft json. So my suggestion is: use proper library (newtownsoft?) to deserialize that json and you should be fine.

Comment: @ Sinatr, yes it's .net core app. Could you please post the code anyways. I will check it. Thanks!

Comment: @user584018 What about [this](https://dotnetfiddle.net/K9w6mW). Doesn't work in the dotnet fiddle but shows a potential work around. Could try it on your machine.

Comment: Thanks @RoadRunner. Works perfectly. Can do do something within class `Data`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think in this case its probably just easier to create your own custom [`JsonConverter<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonconverter-1?view=netcore-3.1) class. Then you don't need to worry about `JsonElement`, and convert the values as they come.

```
public class MyCustomConverter : JsonConverter<Data>
{
    public override Data Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        if (reader.TokenType != JsonTokenType.StartObject)
        {
            throw new JsonException();
        }

        var data = new Data();

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            if (reader.TokenType == JsonTokenType.EndObject)
            {
                return data;
            }

            if (reader.TokenType == JsonTokenType.PropertyName)
            {
                string propertyName = reader.GetString();
                reader.Read();
                switch (propertyName)
                {
                    case "Id":
                        data.Id = reader.GetInt32();
                        break;
                    case "Name":
                        if (reader.TokenType == JsonTokenType.Number)
                        {
                            data.Name = reader.GetInt32();
                        }
                        else if (reader.TokenType == JsonTokenType.String)
                        {
                            data.Name = reader.GetString();
                        }
                        break;
                }
            }

        }
        throw new JsonException();
    }

    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, Data value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        writer.WriteStringValue(value.ToString());
    }
}
```

Then you can add this converter to your JSON serializer settings and deserialize your JSON:

```
var serializeOptions = new JsonSerializerOptions();

serializeOptions.Converters.Add(new MyCustomConverter());

var data = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<Data>>(test, serializeOptions);
```

Full demo on [dotnetfiddle.net](https://dotnetfiddle.net/3AorLV)